# Gradle: same source file in different projects

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have a setup where I have source file `a/b/c.java` under a directory `srcA` and a file with the same name  `a/b/c.java` under a directory `srcB`. I want to exclude this file (or the full package `a/b`) from directory `srcB` and only use those from directory `srcA`, but `srcB` must be part of the source set because it contains other stuff.

A quick example of how I have things configured at the moment (which does not work):

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
        srcDir 'srcA'
        srcDir 'srcB'
        exclude 'srcB/a/b/**'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `exclude { it.file.absolutePath.startsWith("$projectDir/srcB/a/b/") }` (use backslashes on Windows).